# Lambda getting converted to nullptr in cpp

Tags: c++, lambda

Given the following classes:

```
class A
{
    std::function<void()> callback;

public:

    A(std::function<void()> cb) { callback = cb; }

    void trigger()
    {
        if (callback != nullptr)
            callback();
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A array[1] = {
        { [=]() { std::cout << "hello"; } }
    };
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.array[0].trigger();
}
```

why do I get no printout? After some testing, it seems like the `A` constructor is receiving a nullptr instead of the `std::function` of the lambda.

Edit: Thanks to Killzone Kid for fixing my code.

It now compiles and runs which is odd. I will close this question and examine why the code malfunctions in my case.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: **−1** Why are you posting code that doesn't compile? Why not post **the real code**? Voting to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: This code is full of small errors indeed. Missing semicolons, attempts to access private members. Function declarations in main, rather than creating a variable of type B...

Comment: Apologies for the code that does not compile. I meant for it to be a representative example because my actual code is quite complex. 

I am editing the question now to make it compile.

Comment: But as Killzone's answer states. This code works and runs exactly as expected once the mistakes are sorted out.

Comment: That "code" has 6 errors that prevent it from compiling.  It is **not** the code that reproduces your problem.  Always post a [mcve] because your problem is going to be some typo, and I cannot determine what your typo is when I have to rewrite your code to get it to compile, let alone run.  I mean almost 33% of the lines above have errors in them!

Comment: @KillzoneKid, Forgot to credit you, fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
    std::function<void()> callback;

public:

    A(std::function<void()> cb) { callback = cb; }

    void trigger()
    {
        if (callback != nullptr)
            callback();
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A array[1] = {
        { [=]() { std::cout << "hello"; } }
    };
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.array[0].trigger();
}
```

Apart from other (public/private/punctuation) mistakes, this `B b();` is not a class initialization, but `B b;` or `B b{};` is.

Demo: https://ideone.com/t9p1EA

Comment: Thanks man. As above, I will see why this works but my code does not.